# Vue.js get unknown Json key for v-for

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I built a code analysis tool and I want to set my json Data in a vue Table. However, I need the json Key, which is the Package/File name to the directory which data I want to show.

Here is the json Part (NULLY is the Package):

```
"folderStatistics": {
          "NULLY": {
            "Statistiken": {
              "Werte": {
                "Felder": "0",
                "Konstruktoren": "0",
                "Methoden": "8",
                "Klassen": "1",
                "Codezeilen": "191"
              }
            },
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Felder</th>
         <th>Konstruktoren</th>
         <th>Methoden</th>
         <th>Klassen</th>
         <th>Codezeilen</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="value in folderStatistics.NULLY.Statistiken">
         <td>{{$key}}</td>
         <td>{{value.Felder}}</td>
         <td>{{value.Konstruktoren}}</td>
         <td>{{value.Methoden}}</td>
         <td>{{value.Klassen}}</td>
         <td>{{value.Codezeilen}}</td>
         </tr> 
      </tbody>
```

With "NULLY", it works the Directory, but NULLY should be dynamic. 
How can I make that? Does it even work?

Answer (score 2):

[documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for)

You can have `NULLY` in a variable say `package`  and use it in view like  following:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(value, key) in folderStatistics[package].Statistiken">
     <td>{{key}}</td>
     <td>{{value.Felder}}</td>
     <td>{{value.Konstruktoren}}</td>
     <td>{{value.Methoden}}</td>
     <td>{{value.Klassen}}</td>
     <td>{{value.Codezeilen}}</td>
     </tr> 
  </tbody>
```

demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddn4xfkf/).

Comment: yeah okay but NULLY is such a name from the package and i want to make this modular for other uploaded  packages.